# Three.js, custom light geometry

Tags: three.js, webgl, light

Is it possible to create in Three.js a light source that has custom geometry, e.g. symbol. There is Arealight in Three.js that works as rectangular source of light and which has wigth and height parameters.
Finally, the aim is to get a surface illuminated by a such source, which visually is that custom figure.

Thank you WestLangley, this is a great example, I tried this way, but unfortunately, it didn't work for me. I tried this:

```
var textTexture = new THREE.Texture( "textures/text.jpg" );
        //var textTexture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("textures/text.jpg");
        textTexture.format = THREE.RGBFormat;
        textTexture.wrapS = textTexture.wrapT = THREE.MirroredRepeatWrapping;
        textTexture.anisotropy = 4;
        var textLight = new THREE.AreaLight( 0xffffff, 3 );
        textLight.position.set( 10, 5, -5 );
        textLight.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
        textLight.width = 30;
        textLight.height = 10;
        textLight.texture = textTexture;
        scene.add(textLight)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AreaLight` works only with `WebGLDeferredRenderer`, which is quite new, part of the examples (not the library), and there are not a lot of examples of it's use.

If you look at [this example](http://alteredqualia.com/three/examples/webgl_deferred_arealights_texture.html), you can see a movie texture is used as a light source.

In this example, you can substitute another texture for the video texture like so:

```
// texture = new THREE.Texture( video );
texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( "texture.jpg" );
```

Unfortunately, this example is using a modified version of the library.

three.js r.56

Comment: The only way I see is to place a blurred texture to the wall that could be seemed as light illumination. Using THREE.MeshBasicMaterial

Comment: What I suggested works. At some point, what you want to do will be supported, I expect. For now, this is the best you can do. Please remember to "accept" answers by clicking on the check mark. Thank you.

Comment: I tried that you suggested but Arealight shines with ordinary white light. Probably I need something extra to Three.js?

Comment: What I suggested will only work with the modified version of the three.js library that is used in the example I linked to. I do not think it will work with three.js r.56. Sorry. Some day, I expect, it will. You are just a little early. :-)

Comment: This version causes too many errors in my application) I'll fix them in foreseeable future. Anyway, thank you!