# Emit light from a geometry in Three.js

Tags: three.js

Is it possible to have a custom geometry emit light in Three.js?

There is a similar question from 5 years ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14997484/three-js-custom-light-geometry?rq=1).

In my particular case, I have created a TorusGeometry. I would like this torus to also give off light. Is that possible?

Comment: A while ago I was reading something regarding this topic in Three.js. It was still in a test-phase, and there was a sample from some rectangles throwing out light.

Answer (score 1):

The only true way to do this is raytracing, in which case your torus becomes an "emitter" of photons and its geometry is used to calculate the initial directions of said photons.

Otherwise, light technically doesn't exist. Only (mathematical) descriptions of lights exist. (Remember, lights aren't visible/aren't rendered unless you're using a `LightHelper`.) These descriptions are used by material shaders, which use the light descriptions (and other objects in the scene, in the case of shadows) to determine the color the current fragment should contribute to a pixel.

With this in mind, if you could write a shader to handle a torus-shaped light, then all you need to do is provide that light's information to the shader. You can do this by extending a `THREE.js` light class to make your own `TorusLight` to add to the scene, then give the objects in your scene your custom shader.

THAT SAID, if you'd be satisfied with simulating the torus light, and want a visible torus, you can always add a `PointLight` at the position of your torus (or several throughout the body of the torus), and give your torus some kind of glow effect.

Comment: Thanks @thejim01, are there any examples or some place I can find docs on how to extend THREE.js light class to make my own TorusLight?

Adding a bunch of PointLights in the shape of a torus sounds much easier, but I'm wondering how to go about it using the method of creating an actual TorusLight.

Comment: In the THREE.js code, look for `function Light` and `function PointLight`. `PointLight` extends `Light`. That said, if you're going to group a bunch of `PointLight`s together, you might be better off extending `Object3D` or `Group` so you don't confuse the renderer. (`Light`s carry the `isLight` flag, which is used for optimization when collecting the scene lights.)